# Why am I unable to connect to /usr/bin/chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on my project, where i need to press a button by Selenium. But when i start it, it gives me this error

```
/home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:139:in `connect_until_stable': unable to connect to /usr/bin/chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
    from /home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:57:in `block in start'
    from /home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:41:in `locked'
    from /home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:54:in `start'
    from /home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:84:in `launch'
    from /home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:374:in `service_url'
    from /home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:311:in `create_bridge'
    from /home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:74:in `initialize'
    from /home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `new'
    from /home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `for'
    from /home/yarikhrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
    from test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Code:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome
driver.get "https://www.google.com/"
driver.find_element(:xpath, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[2]').click
```

How can i fix this? I've found that there is may be some problems with google dependencies, but I clearly don't understand how to change it

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Added, pressing button on www.google.com

Comment: Does the ChromeDriver initiated Chrome browser spins up successfully?

Comment: How to check it?

Answer (score 1):

Two points from my side.

First off, check whether `chromedriver.exe` exists in `c:\ruby30\bin` If you use other version of ruby, then you would be finding ruby accordingly like ruby26 ruby 27 etc.

You look like you are using Linux operating system, eh? If so, check whether `chromedriver.exe` is on right path.

Second off,

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[2]').click
```

this one is the old style, it is not working now.

Use this code

```
driver.find_element(xpath: '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[2]').click
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (if i remember correct). I searched for chromedriver.exe in my WSL, but didn't find anything. How to install it correctly and in what directory?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Linux but your error message says that it's searching here `usr/bin/chromedriver` so try locating there.

Comment: Yeah, I found a file named chromedriver in usr/bin. What am I supposed to do with it?

Comment: Then I don't know it supposed to work. Your given code works for me in windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when setting up WSL 2. Updating to the newest version of WSL by running `wsl --update` in powershell fixed the issue.

I am using Linux Chrome and Chromedriver, not Windows. My distro is Ubuntu 20.04. To install these I did the following:

Installing Chrome

```
sudo apt install fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libgbm1 libnspr4 libnss3 libxss1 xdg-utils
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
echo 'alias chrome="google-chrome-stable"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
```

Installing Chromedriver

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```